# Firebase database sync with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am willing to develop an application in which I would download users phone contacts from Firebase and match it with Phonebook to show the Common values.

My Design Approach is as below:

**Repeat this when `PhonebookUserRecord.Count()` changes. But Run it Once during Signup**:

1. Download user phone data from Firebase in `FireBaseUSER` Array list.
2. Then Get all phone numbers from Phone Book and then match it and Store it in a `FinalPHONEdata` Arraylist and Store the NON-matching list in `NONmatchUserPhone` arraylist.
3. Then place the Data into SQLite database.

Display the data into List view from SQLite in the List view last updated data is displayed and as the SQLite database updates , it shows the newly available data.

Note: In order to run the above Service, user has to add a Phone book Contact after the signup.

Please rectify if I am wrong. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: So you're asking about whether your logic is correct or not? I think it is good.